# Filter rows in polars Dataframe where the rows are list

Tags: python, python-polars

I want to filter a polars dataframe  based in a column where the values are a list.

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
{
    "foo": [[1, 3, 5], [2, 6, 7], [3, 8, 10]],
    "bar": [6, 7, 8],
    "ham": ["a", "b", "c"],
})
```

I want a filter that returns every row that column "foo" has the value 3.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what it is you're doing with the result, it may be beneficial to `.explode` the list column.

In which case you could use:

```
>>> df.with_row_count().explode("foo").filter((pl.col("foo") == 3).any().over("row_nr"))
shape: (6, 4)
┌────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ row_nr ┆ foo ┆ bar ┆ ham │
│ ---    ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ u32    ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str │
╞════════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0      ┆ 1   ┆ 6   ┆ a   │
│ 0      ┆ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ a   │
│ 0      ┆ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ a   │
│ 2      ┆ 3   ┆ 8   ┆ c   │
│ 2      ┆ 8   ┆ 8   ┆ c   │
│ 2      ┆ 10  ┆ 8   ┆ c   │
└────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you want to do something with a list type column, you'll want to use the `.arr` namespace of expressions. In this case it's [`.arr.contains`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.arr.contains.html)

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
{
    "foo": [[1, 3, 5], [2, 6, 7], [3, 8, 10]],
    "bar": [6, 7, 8],
    "ham": ["a", "b", "c"],
})

df.filter(pl.col('foo').arr.contains(3))

shape: (2, 3)
┌────────────┬─────┬─────┐
│ foo        ┆ bar ┆ ham │
│ ---        ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ list[i64]  ┆ i64 ┆ str │
╞════════════╪═════╪═════╡
│ [1, 3, 5]  ┆ 6   ┆ a   │
│ [3, 8, 10] ┆ 8   ┆ c   │
└────────────┴─────┴─────┘
```